# Extracting integer from the paragraph

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-re

i am trying to extract only the fees amount from the paragraph but i am facing the problem. there is two fees amount and i want 2 of them. this is my code for: http://www.reading.ac.uk/ready-to-study/study/subject-area/modern-languages-and-european-studies-ug/ba-spanish-and-history.aspx

```
fees_div = soup.find('div', class_='Fees hiddenContent pad-around-large tabcontent')
if fees_div:
    fees_list = fees_div.find_all('\d+','p')
    course_data['Fees'] = fees_list
    print('fees : ', fees_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this please:

```
In [10]: import requests
In [11]: from bs4 import *
In [12]: page = requests.get('http://www.reading.ac.uk/ready-to-study/study/subject-area/modern-languages-and-european-studies-ug/ba-spanish-and-history.aspx')
In [13]: soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
In [14]: [x for x in soup.find('div', class_='Fees hiddenContent pad-around-large tabcontent').text.split() if u"\xA3" in x]
Out[14]: ['£9,250*', '£17,320']
```

Comment: This runs for me but the first fee has a trailing '*', which I don't think is desirable.

Comment: `[x.replace('*','') for x in soup.find('div', class_='Fees hiddenContent pad-around-large tabcontent').text.split() if u"\xA3" in x]` should do the job.

Comment: Thank you so much it works if i run like this but i am using another link extraction python file, so i think thats causing problem

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

r = requests.get('http://www.reading.ac.uk/ready-to-study/study/subject-area/modern-languages-and-european-studies-ug/ba-spanish-and-history.aspx')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,  'html.parser')
fees_div = soup.find('div', class_='Fees hiddenContent pad-around-large tabcontent')
m = re.search(r'£[\d,]+', fees_div.select('p:nth-of-type(2)')[0].get_text())
fee1 = m[0]
m = re.search(r'£[\d,]+', fees_div.select('p:nth-of-type(3)')[0].get_text())
fee2 = m[0]
print(fee1, fee2)
```

Prints:

```
£9,250 £17,320
```

**Update**

You can also scrape the page using Selenium, although in this case it offers no advantage. For example (using Chhrome):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("headless")
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('http://www.reading.ac.uk/ready-to-study/study/subject-area/modern-languages-and-european-studies-ug/ba-spanish-and-history.aspx')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,  'html.parser')
fees_div = soup.find('div', class_='Fees hiddenContent pad-around-large tabcontent')
m = re.search(r'£[\d,]+', fees_div.select('p:nth-of-type(2)')[0].get_text())
fee1 = m[0]
m = re.search(r'£[\d,]+', fees_div.select('p:nth-of-type(3)')[0].get_text())
fee2 = m[0]
print(fee1, fee2)
driver.quit()
```

**Update**

Consider just using the following: Just scan the entire HTML source without using BeautifulSoup looking for the fees using a simple regular expression `findall`:

```
import requests
import re

r = requests.get('http://www.reading.ac.uk/ready-to-study/study/subject-area/modern-languages-and-european-studies-ug/ba-spanish-and-history.aspx')
print(re.findall(r'£[\d,]+', r.text))
```

Prints:

```
['£9,250', '£17,320']
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Downloads/pythonProject/Undergraduate/Undergraduate_script.py", line 107, in <module>
    m = re.search(r'£[\d,]+', fees_div.select('p:nth-of-type(2)')[0].get_text())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'select'

Comment: Neither my code nor the code offered by @idar seems to run for you, Are you running with the latest version of BeautifulSoup? And what version of Python are you using?

Comment: Maybe the way i am getting the links is affecting it

Comment: i wanted to show the code but i cannot show it, as it changes the format. i have another python file which extracts the code so i have to use that python file for the links

Comment: You need to post a Minimal Reproducible Example. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: oh okay i am new to it i am really sorry. thank you for your help. here is link to my code can you please go through is possible: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hrILNp9MKMMKNmzqtl-FfbgZWNiBwXbRrsxAj-P7V04/edit?usp=sharing t

Comment: I don't see what the code in that link directly has to do with your question. I see that it is code that uses Selenium to scrape a page (but not your page) rather than `requests`. I have updated my answer to do likewise. The result is the same -- it just runs more slowly. Question: You never stated in your post what precisely the result you expected were (you should have). Are the two values I print out those values?

Comment: i am scrapping this website. Now i wants the fees value to be printed. So i put that overall code to show how am i getting the links and overview of the code.

Comment: It worked for me, thank you for your help

Comment: it works for few links then it displays following error:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Downloads/pythonProject/Undergraduate/Undergraduate_script.py", line 166, in <module>
    m = re.search(r'£[\d,]+', fees_div.select('p:nth-of-type(2)')[0].get_text())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'select'

Comment: So now you are trying this against a different URL and it appears that `fees_div = soup.find('div', class_='Fees hiddenContent pad-around-large tabcontent')` is returning `None` so the next statement throws an exception. You would need to add a test to see if `None` is being returned. I am also assuming that the fees are always in the 2nd and 3rd paragraphs within this <div>, which may or may not always be the case. See my updated answer.

Comment: Ohh the problem is some websites are crashing so thats causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('http://www.reading.ac.uk/ready-to-study/study/subject-area/modern-languages-and-european-studies-ug/ba-spanish-and-history.aspx')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
item = soup.find(id='Panel5').text
fees = re.findall(r"students:[^£]+(.*?)[*\s]",item)
print(fees)
```

Output:

```
['£9,250', '£17,320']
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works individually but with my code it doesnt work i am trying to adjust it.